# What's a good way to put times into an enum?

Tags: enums

I want to do the following, but I can't start an enum entry with a number. I feel like writing `FiveMin, TenMin`, etc. won't be as user-friendly. Is there another naming convention I could do?

```
enum RushTime { 5m = 5, 15m = 15, 30m = 30, 1h = 60, 2h = 120, 3h = 180, 6h = 360, 12h = 720, 1d = 1440, 2d = 2880 }
```

Comment: Without any other context, it seems like an enum is not the right way to go about handling this data, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @AndrewArnold It's for a dropdown element for items in a game. Each will have a wait time out of the specific options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix with a `t` or a `T`, like in `t5m`, `t3h` and so on.

Comment: That seems like a logical thing to do. I ended up using your suggestion but putting an underscore instead of a 't'.